# How to recognise a dialogue in robotium

Tags: android, android-activity, robotium

I'm new to Robotium as well as Android. I have written some code to test an activity. and that activity is opening a dialogue box. and i'm not able to identify it. I tried solo.getCurrentActivity(), not workes. I tried solo.searchText(). But test is failing.

Answer (score 0):

write code like this

```
if (solo.waitForActivity("HomePhone", 20000)) {
            if(solo.waitForText("xxx*",1,10000)){
                if(solo.waitForText("ok*",1,5000)){
                    solo.clickOnText("ok*");                    
                }else{
                    solo.goBack();
                }
            }
```

wait for text is best method for your purpose